# Зацепится за тег для дальнейшего парсинга страницы

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, python-3.9

Есть следующая страница: [ссылка](https://knute.edu.ua/blog/read/?pid=1038&uk)

Я хочу распарсить следующий блок[image: скрин], но никак не могу зацепится за "Розклад екзаменаційної сесії", чтобы дальше продолжить.

Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
#print(dir(requests))
# модуль `get` відповідає за зчитування ресурса в об'єкт 'response'
#requests.get
# отримаємо сторінку розкладів 
url = 'https://knute.edu.ua/blog/read/?pid=1038&uk'
resp = requests.get(url)
#print(dir(resp))
resp.text[:500]
resp.encoding
resp.apparent_encoding
resp.encoding = resp.apparent_encoding
#print(resp.text[:500])
knteu_rasp_page = resp.text
# застосуємо html-парсер до завантаженої сторінки з розкладами 'knteu_rasp_page'
parsed_rasp = bs(knteu_rasp_page, features='html.parser')
# print(dir(parsed_rasp))
back = parsed_rasp.find('span', string = "РОЗКЛАД ЕКЗАМЕНАЦІЙНОЇ СЕСІЇ")
print(back)
```

Поправьте, пожалуйста, где я не так делаю.

Comment: А что вам по итогу нужно? Если вытянуть данные только один раз, то взять все таблицы с классом "table table-striped" и потом ковырять 6-ю и 7-ю (это для потренькаться). Или вообще, скопировать данные вручную и поудалять ненужное в np++ (это чисто для данных единоразово). Для многократного же и умного парсинга нужно малость поколдовать.

Comment: По итогу мне нужно получить датафрейм из трёх колонок: факультет - курс - ссылка на файлик.

Comment: Ну, мне кажется, его проще вручную вытащить, чем колдовать с кодом.

Comment: https://it.do.am/tu.xlsx - вот вам заготовка

Comment: у тебя проблеммы с кодировкой, выводил resp.text?

Comment: Спасибо за файлик, но нужен программный код. А с кодировкой проблем я не вижу, все нормально в консоли VSCode отображается